# filtering out specific keys in an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am writing out the key/value pair of an object.  I'm trying to filter out 2 of the keys in the object like this:

```
{Object.entries(params.char).filter('Attribute1').filter('Attribute2').map(([key,value], index) => <Text key={key}>{key}</Text>)}
```

Here is one of the objects in "paramas":

```
{
    id: 1,
    Name: "Drax Bravesword",
    Rating: "*****",
    XP: 392
Age: 34
    Avatar: require('./images/profile1.png'),
    Map: require('./images/map_1.png'),
    Attribute1: "Power",
    Attribute2: "Knowledge",
    Attribute3: "Family"
}
```

However when I run this, I get this error:

> "Array.prototype.filter callback must be a function"

I'm not quite sure how to fix this, but is there a way to fix it or am I doing this all wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=control) array method accepts function as argument, not string. So please use this:

```
Object.entries(params.char).filter((item) => (item.indexOf('Attribute1') || item.indexOf('Attribute2') > -1 ))...
```

```js
let ob = {
  Attribute1: 11,
  Attribute2: 22,
  Attribute3: 33
};

console.log('Not filtered', Object.entries(ob));
let result = Object.entries(ob).filter((item) => (item.indexOf('Attribute1') > -1 || item.indexOf('Attribute2') > -1 ));

console.log('Filtered:', result)
```

Comment: I tried this, and while it got rid of the error, it is still shows all 3 attributes.

Comment: I've updated answer and added code snippet and it seems to work fine.

Comment: oh wait, do I need to remove the " .map(([key,value], index) => " portion of my code?  Does "filter" replace "map" in this case?  Thanks!

Comment: No, you still need the `map`. `filter` only filters properties but `map` is responsible for returning components.

Answer (score 1):

From what I'm understanding, you want to only make text elements for attributes 1 and 2, you won't have to chain the filters...you can do it in one go:

```
{Object.entries(params.char).filter(touple =>
   (touple[0] === 'Attribute1' || touple[0] === 'Attribute2')).map(touple => <Text key={touple[0]}>{touple[0]}</Text>)}
```

Comment: I'm trying to write out everything in the object except for 2 pieces(Attribute1 and Attribute2).  I want to filter those out so they don't show up on the screen.  Thanks!

Comment: then you can just switch the === to !== so it grabs everything other than those two, or you can use lodash's omit which will return everything other than the keys you pass it

Comment: This will not work since `entries` method returns an array fo arrays. Please check `Object.entries` doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Comment: Ah haven't really used it before, so if you want the key it'll just be the first index of that touple. i'll update my code thanks. You could also use Object.keys if you only need the keys

Answer (score 0):

You almost did it by yourself :)

Here is the answer:

```
render() {
  const textElements = Object.entries(params.char)
    .filter(([key]) => key !== 'Attribute1' && key !== 'Attribute2')
    .map(([key, value]) => <Text key={key}>{key}, {value}</Text>);

  return (
    <View>
      {textElements}
    </View>
  );
}
```