# ES6 - Filter an Object based on True values

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have an Object which contains some booleans like this:

```
{ date: "2017-10-05", name_change: false, age_change: true, ... }
```

I want to `filter()` the keys which are true.
I also need the date value. how can I make this `filter`?

Regards.

Comment: It is not a duplicate!

Comment: Then you need to explain your problem better, because it sure looks like a duplicate currrently

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul - he's filtering the properties of an object, not objects in an array.

Comment: @OriDrori, OK so that's a possible interpretation, but given he's also saying he wants to use `filter()`, not the only one. In either case, an edit to clarify the question would have been preferable to just declaring it wasn't a duplicate.

Comment: And that's still a duplicate of a different question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439907/filtering-out-specific-keys-in-an-object and also answered in this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35370646/filtering-object-by-keys-in-lodash (and probably others)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Object.entries()` to convert the object to an array of [key, value] tuples. Filter the tuples by check if the value is `true`. Convert back to an object using `Object.fromEntries()`:

```js
const obj = { 
  date: "2017-10-05", 
  name_change: false, 
  age_change: true 
};

const result = Object.fromEntries(
  Object
    .entries(obj)
    .filter(([, val]) => val !== true)
);

console.log(result);
```

**Old answer**:

Get the keys with [Object#keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), and then iterate the array of keys with [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce?v=b), and build a new object that doesn't contain keys which value equals to `true`:

```js
const obj = { 
  date: "2017-10-05", 
  name_change: false, 
  age_change: true 
};

const result = Object.keys(obj)
  .reduce((o, key) => {
    obj[key] !== true && (o[key] = obj[key]);

    return o;
  }, {});

console.log(result);
```